# Unable to read data from the node even when firebase security rule is set to true

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase database with a topics node which contain various topics. When I try to apply read rule on the this node I am able to read the value in the firebase security rule simulator but not in my actual app. But if I apply the rule to the parent node itself I am able to fetch the value.

Here is my database:
[image]

Below is  my firebase security rule:

```
  {
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      "$user_id":{
        ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('blocked/'+$user_id+'/'+auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "topics":{
      //".read": "true",
      "$topic_id":{
        //restricting blocked users from reading the topcis
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Now if i uncomment this ".read" rule on the parent node I am able to read but not when I apply it with the wildcard. I am also able to write to the topic node perfectly fine.

This is the function where I am trying to access the data from firebase database.

```
public void loadTopics() {
        //Load topics for the first time
        createTopicFab.show();
        Query topicQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child(FirebaseValues.TOPICS_TABLE).limitToLast(TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD).orderByChild("createdTimestamp");
        itemPos = 0;
        topics.clear();
        topicIds.clear();
        topicQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                // Add the values in the topics list and notify the adapter
                loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Topics topic = dataSnapshot.getValue(Topics.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "loadTopics(), Topic: " + topic.getText());
                topics.add(0, topic);
                if (itemPos++ == 0) {
                    //first key
                    lastKey = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }
                topicIds.add(0, dataSnapshot.getKey());
                topicsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefTopic.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // remove the values in the topics list and notify the adapter
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Also, please don't show pictures of code.  Copy any text into the question formatted as code so it's easier to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson The problem is not with the code but with the security rules, Also there was no better way of posting that data structure.

Comment: The security rules are plain text and could have easily been inserted into the question.  If you don't show code, then all you have here is a bug report that can't be diagnosed, because we can't reproduce the problem in the exact way that you're seeing it.

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, I edited the question and copy pasted the rules.

Comment: Also add the code, please.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the required code too.

Comment: Your code is trying to read from /topics but your rules are for /topics/@topicID. For those rules to work you have to move them one lvl up. Also the child you are using for orderByChild doesn't seem to exist in you datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

This is your base query:

```
Query topicQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child(FirebaseValues.TOPICS_TABLE)
```

I assume that `FirebaseValues.TOPIC_TABLE` is "topics".  This query can't read the children at /topics because you haven't given read access at that location.  When you give access to /topics, it will work, as you've observed.  The location of the query is all that matters - the permission of the children don't matter in the case.  Security rules will not "filter" the children under the location for you.  Read the documentation about "[security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)".

Comment: I get what you're saying but I need to restrict blocked users from reading topics posted by the user who blocked them. How do I implement that then?

Comment: That's well beyond the scope of this question. Please ask another question that explains the problem, and what you've tried already to solve it. You will likely need a different database structure.

Comment: Before opening a new questions, I recommend first searching for previous [questions mentioning "rules are not filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters), as this (admittedly confusing) topic has been covered a lot before already.